# Troubleshooting remote iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone

a customer reports that the screen is black like in pic2. It is supposed to be like pic 1 with a row of "Achievements", "Inactive", and also gray background and not black. Do you have any idea what could be happening here? Is there an easy way for the customer to send me the local data file? Other suggestions?

[image: Developer]
[image: Customer]

Comment: Maybe this coulde be related to simulator vs. device? The first image is simulator, the other is device. I get a new device next week for further testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Apple Support:

It looks like the problem was the `taskViewController`’s `initWithCoder:` method not doing `self=[super initWithCoder:aDecoder];`

After I added the call to super, so that the class could be properly initialized, and the problem went away.